# How to move an imageView inside of the Table Cell's Prototype Cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, imageview, tableview

I have been just learning Swift language and I am pretty new at this.

I am trying to create a table view with protoype cell containing a ImageView. I want "ImageView" make centered according to x Axis with "main storyoard". At first glance, everything is good until I open the simulator. After opening the simualator, I see that it was absoulutely not centered on x-axis. (I am sure that my simulator's phone type and my storyboard's phone type is true.)

Here, I want to center the imageView with code. But I can't figure out where I should put the code.

I am trying to put this code if it is available. (I guess it should be.) If you have any suggestion to just relocate the x-axis of the imageview, I am totally open.

```
    let width = view.frame.size.width
    
    var frm: CGRect = imageView!.frame
    frm.origin.x = (width/2) - (frm.midX/2)
    frm.origin.y = frm.origin.y
    frm.size.width = frm.size.width
    frm.size.height = frm.size.height
    cell.imageView!.frame = frm
```

**In order to put the code, I am 2 class types: "UITableViewCell" and "UIViewController" Which one and how should I put the code?**

**How should align the imageView inside of the that tableView?**

I added all unfinished project to this link. This is not a serious project. Just a project serving to learners.

https://github.com/mmtbey/SwiftFirebase_InstaClone

**To sign in:**

**username: trial@trial.com**

**password: 123456**

Thank you.

*Note: I can align the frame of imageView on storyboard easily. However, centering on x-axis doesn't work in deed. When I run the simulator, I see the image left-aligned. I can fix the situation by inreasing the gap between left line and imageView. But that is not a proper way in order to solve the problem.*

[image: Storyboard view]

[image: simulator view]

[image: My constraints and output]

[image: ImageView]

[image: my_CellView]

[image: ContentView]

[image: TableView]

Comment: try playing with the constraints instead of the frame

Comment: in size inspector section, below the position view property in the layout you have a layout property, can you set it to autoresizing mask and then feedback it to me.

Comment: and alse in contentview size inspector, below the layout margin property, check the preserve superview magins -> true after that feedback to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using auto layout, I don't think you should try to fix it using frames.

Fixing it with auto layout is what I recommend.

Looking at your Storyboard image, it does not seem like you are setting the `centerX` and `centerY` constraints.

Here is how you do it:

[image: Center constraints swift iOS Storboard]

[image: Autolayout constraints UITableView center image in table view cell swift iOS]

On doing that, things should center properly:

[image: Center UITableViewCell image swift iOS storyboard auto layout constraints]

Comment: Dear Shawn Frank, I added center-x constraint, however it still does the same. I added a new photo showing my constraints and my output properly. Thank you.

Comment: @MMT - did you remove the frame calculation you did programmatically and only keep autolayout constraints ?

Comment: @MMT - something seems a bit off as even your `userEmail` label is aligned to center but it is showing to the left .. is this expected or also an undesirable result ?

Comment: @MMT - please can you also expand your tableview constraints to the view

Comment: What is your table view constraint?, top,right,left,bottom?
you must add constraint to table view.

Comment: @ShawnFrank My userEmail label is centered but it seems on left because of the left-allignment. So it is expected result for me. I removed my aligning code from the project and I added all unfinished project to my question field with a gitHub link. If you want to glance to my unfinished project, you can use the username: "trial@trial.com" and password: "123456"

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar My table view constraints are zero to every edge. .0 mm to upperside, .0 mm to left, right and lower side. In other words, my table view has been arrenged to cover all screen.

Comment: plz select your table view cell and content view and then see and check the right pane of size inspector(2th tab in right side) can you share it.

Comment: for each one table view cell view and content view check the size inspector and share the pics.

Comment: @MMT - I cannot compile your project however I took the Feed ViewController into another project and ran it. Something seems a bit off because I see the image is centered properly but the user email does not appear at all plus there are several constraint warnings. This is what I see: http://prntscr.com/igkJaS1enyYJ

Comment: @ShawnFrank I cared with all warning and they have disappear on that viewcontroller. Thank you. I guess I will delete the all viewcontroller and create again if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a bug here and I could not find a way to fix the situation. However, I deleted all constraits inside of the viewController and I coded the constraints like below.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    
    
    let myWidth = contentView.frame.size.width - 90
    let myHeight = myWidth - 90
    
    
    UserEmailLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 30,
                                  y: 10,
                                  width: 200 ,
                                  height: 20)
    UserEmailLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    
    
    imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: contentView.frame.size.width/2 - myWidth/2 ,
                              y: UserEmailLabel.frame.maxY + 20,
                                   width: myWidth,
                                   height: myHeight)
    
    CommentLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 30,
                                y: (imageView?.frame.maxY)!,
                                width: myWidth - 30 ,
                                height: contentView.frame.size.height/10)
    
    LikeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: myWidth + 20,
                             y: CommentLabel.frame.maxY,
                             width: 30,
                             height: contentView.frame.size.height/10)
    
    LikeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    LikeLabel.textAlignment = .right
    
    LikeLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    
    LikeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 45,
                              y: CommentLabel.frame.maxY,
                              width: 40,
                              height: contentView.frame.size.height/10)
    
    
}
```

Have a nice day.